# Start program maximized

Tags: windows-8

I'm running Windows 8 and was using [SQLiteStudio](http://sqlitestudio.one.pl/) normally.

I don't remember what went wrong but now, after I run the program, it always stars minimized like this

[image]

And the program does not run. The only option that does anything is the minimize buttons. All other don't work. On windows task manager it is showing as not responding. It is just consuming resources and being hang.

I've tried this solutions but without any positive result.

1 - Create a shortcut and picking to start maximized.

2 - In CMD start /MAX sqlitestudio.exe

3 - Downloaded the program again (it's a single executable file) and it starts minimized

4 - Searched for windows keys in registry and deleted the ones referring to sqlitestudio and nothing

5 - Restarted the PC.

6 - Tried to run on different compatibility (windows 7 and windows xp) and the result is the same

Do you have any other recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've leaved the program to run for about one hour and then it finally came up to like.

The problem was that when I've closed the program I left almost 9000 lines on the SQL query editor. That lines were kept in the program memory and, in the next run, have to be loaded so this was probably the cause...

Answer (score 0):

Could it be you have the wrong version? I see there are several versions of SQLight at that site.  I downloaded the first option 32-bit Windows, it launched from a shortcut maximized.

That said it seems a moody program, I had to click through a few security warnings.  My thinking, if you have tightened up on security, that could be what's stopping it.

So my last suggestion, undo the last thing you did.

Answer (score 0):

Try using CCleaner to clear the Window size / location cache from your windows installation